# Unique identify linux machine

Tags: ubuntu

I'm sending some information via a bash script (on a cron job) from a variety of ubuntu machines to a central server, and I need to uniquely identify each machine so I know which stats pertain to each machine.

I could enforce some kind of token on each machine, but I'd prefer something automated.

On the face of it `/etc/machine-id` would work in most cases, but there is one situation in which it wouldn't work - if the virtual machine is cloned and a new instance launched (e.g. in AWS or Digital Ocean), then I assume that we would have duplicate machine-id's ?

Are there any other alternatives that I can use?

Comment: how do you send that information? Which protocol is used?

Comment: @MilošĐakonović at the moment its being sent via curl

Comment: Why isn't the IP address enough? Or the SSH host key (this should be regenerated for every machine, even if you clone it)? Or the MAC address of a network interface?

Comment: IP addresses are not guaranteed to be unique, I'd imagine 192.168.1.2 exists on many different LANs.  MAC address in software isn't much better, everyone is making up addresses for their VM interfaces.   SSH public host key would be a good choice if it was recreated after cloning the instance, its random and near certain unique.

Comment: Host name was also suggested. Each of host name (in DNS), IP address, MAC address is unique on one network, and provides useful information. However conflicts are possible between networks sharing the same naming conventions. I like where you are going with machine-id, as random UUID style identifiers are near certain globally unique.

Answer (score 4):

You could use machine-id. Remove `/etc/machine-id`  from your VM template images. Note that systemd will re-create it if you boot the image again, which is desirable on the clones but not on the template image. And if it is missing, you can generate one on a cloned instance with `systemd-machine-id-setup`.

Or generate your own identifier. It would be straightforward to write the output of `uuidgen`  (from util-linux)  to a file in an install script or init script.